# e.force:refreshView and e.force:showToast not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

These salesforce events are not working in my case. I have used them earlier w/o any problem but currently they are not working. Can somebody tell me what do we need to do in this case? Do we need to extend something...handle these events or anything else?

UPDATE:

I can see in console.log that toast event is getting generated and it has all parameters in it, but its just not shown on screen.
Also, if the components are added in app through lightning app builder or Salesforce 1, the toast is fired. Just wondering what is it that I am missing????  Is toast not fired on vf pages or standalone apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got answer in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149701/are-toasts-not-generated-in-standalone-app-or-in-vf-page) question. They don't work in VF / classic view or in standalone apps.