# Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined when trying to implement lightning custom Action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I am trying to implement custom action in lightning . The below controller code is to add two numbers and display using toast. It is however throwing the error :

> Action failed: c:CustomAction$controller$clickAdd [Cannot read
>   property 'setParams' of undefined]

The js controller code is:

```
({
clickAdd: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Get the values from the form
    var n1 = component.find("num1").get("v.value");
    var n2 = component.find("num2").get("v.value");
    // Display the total in a "toast" status message
    var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    resultsToast.setParams({
        "title": "Quick Add: " + n1 + " + " + n2,
        "message": "The total is: " + (n1 + n2) + "."
    });


    resultsToast.fire();
        // Close the action panel
var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        dismissActionPanel.fire();
    }
})
```

The component code is :

```
    <!--quickAdd.cmp-->
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction">
    <!-- Very simple addition -->
<lightning:input type="number" name="myNumber" aura:id="num1" label="Number 1"/> +
    <lightning:input type="number" name="myNumber" aura:id="num2" label="Number 2"/>
    <br/>
    <lightning:button label="Add" onclick="{!c.clickAdd}"/>
</aura:component>
```

I have copied this piece of code directly from the standard lightning guide.

Comment: Do you call this Lightning component from your Lightning quick action?

Comment: Yes the component implements lightningQuickAction.

Comment: Could you post your whole code? Because this is supposed to work.

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: you must be trying to access it through Standalone app like /c/NameOfApp.app, isn't that the case?

Comment: Yeah that's correct.

Comment: @starhunter When I was asking if you were calling the component from a Lightning quick action I was talking about referencing it directly from the quick action. Which is possible. Calling it inside a Lightning application is not calling it from a quick action obviously.

Comment: by the way, have you tried to add something like <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:showToast" type="EVENT"/> to the component?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways how you can access a lightning component.

1. You can access lightning component from a standalone app accessed like /c/NameOfApp.app
2. You can access it from a lightning tab
3. You can access it from a lightning flexi page.
4. You can access it from Visualforce.

Event `e.force:showToast` is available only for 2 and 3 case. And you must be trying to access it through Standalone app like /c/NameOfApp.app

Comment: Where does this comes from? I'm using the `e.force:showToast` event in my Lightning quick actions and this is working fine.

Comment: this question has actually already been asked
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149512/e-forcerefreshview-and-e-forceshowtoast-not-working 

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149701/are-toasts-not-generated-in-standalone-app-or-in-vf-page

Comment: Yes but where did you find any documentation about the fact that force:showToast events are not working in a lightning quick action?

Comment: I mean that force:showToast are not available in standalone app or in lightning out for visualforce. I haven't tried whether this works or not in global actions or quick actions